# How to print an array in an array from JSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, multidimensional-array

so i am trying to print all the names of the friends array in a single line with commas , ( I am trying to learn JS and JSON and have very less programming knowldge)
here is my data file from the internet
http://www.json-generator.com/

my array
    [
      {
        "age": 25,
        "eyeColor": "blue",
        "name": "Leon Pickett",
        "phone": "+1 (834) 535-2787",
        "balance": "$3,632.41",
        "address": "856 Woodhull Street, Southmont, Wisconsin, 373",
        "friends": [
          {"id": 0,"name": "Bonnie Dudley"},
          {"id": 1,"name": "Blair Hopkins"},
          {"id": 2,"name": "Burris Lara"}
        ],},
      {
        "age": 29,
        "eyeColor": "brown",
        "name": "Rosales Raymond",
        "balance": "$3,632.41",
        "phone": "+1 (935) 462-3887",
        "address": "745 Havens Place, Norvelt, Florida, 6999",
        "friends": [
          {"id": 0,"name": "Theresa Burt"},
          {"id": 1,"name": "Mooney Whitney"},
          {"id": 2,"name": "Hebert Gill"}
        ]}]

here is my code

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var txt = "jsontst1.txt";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    myFunction(myArr);
  }
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", txt, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(arr) {
  var out = "";
  var out2 = "";
  var i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var frndlngth = arr[i].friends.length;

    for (j = 0; j < frndlngth; j++) {
      var frnds = arr[i].friends[j];
      out2 += frnds.name;
    }

    out +=
      "Name = " + arr[i].name + "<br>" +
      "Age = " + arr[i].age + "<br>" +
      "Phone = " + arr[i].phone + "<br>" +
      "Balance = " + arr[i].balance + "<br>" +
      "Eyecolor = " + arr[i].eyeColor + "<br>" +
      "Address = " + arr[i].address + "<br>" +
      "Friends = " + out2 + "<hr>";
  }

  document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
```

in output the Friends displays value of previous array also ? what am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: What is the value for argument `arr`?

Comment: it is my array in a separate file , the content of file is extracted from http://www.json-generator.com/ .

Comment: Can you share that array as well ?

Comment: [
  {
    "age": 25,
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "name": "Leon Pickett",
    "phone": "+1 (834) 535-2787",
    "balance": "$3,632.41",
    "address": "856 Woodhull Street, Southmont, Wisconsin, 373",
    "friends": [
      {"id": 0,"name": "Bonnie Dudley"},
      {"id": 1,"name": "Blair Hopkins"},
      {"id": 2,"name": "Burris Lara"}
    ],},
  ] the array is too big to post here , i am putting only one set of data in the array.

Comment: Use **Array.prototype.join** if you need a string joined from each item of an array. For example, here is `var friends = ['John', 'Mary'];` and `friends.join(', ');`, and you'll get `"John, Mary"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason is `out2` variable is global hence value is being appended in it, not resetting it after outer loop.

Make it local in a `for-loop`

```js
function myFunction(arr) {
  var out = "";
  var i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var out2 = "";
    var frndlngth = arr[i].friends.length;
    for (j = 0; j < frndlngth; j++) {
      var frnds = arr[i].friends[j];
      out2 += frnds.name;
    }
    out +=
      "Name = " + arr[i].name + "<br>" +
      "Age = " + arr[i].age + "<br>" +
      "Phone = " + arr[i].phone + "<br>" +
      "Balance = " + arr[i].balance + "<br>" +
      "Eyecolor = " + arr[i].eyeColor + "<br>" +
      "Address = " + arr[i].address + "<br>" +
      "Friends = " + out2 + "<hr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
var input = [{
  "age": 25,
  "eyeColor": "blue",
  "name": "Leon Pickett",
  "phone": "+1 (834) 535-2787",
  "balance": "$3,632.41",
  "address": "856 Woodhull Street, Southmont, Wisconsin, 373",
  "friends": [{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Bonnie Dudley"
  }, {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Blair Hopkins"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Burris Lara"
  }],
}, {
  "age": 29,
  "eyeColor": "brown",
  "name": "Rosales Raymond",
  "balance": "$3,632.41",
  "phone": "+1 (935) 462-3887",
  "address": "745 Havens Place, Norvelt, Florida, 6999",
  "friends": [{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Theresa Burt"
  }, {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Mooney Whitney"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Hebert Gill"
  }]
}];
myFunction(input);
```

```html
<div id="id01"></div>
```

### [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/fndc071e/1/)

Comment: thanks soo much , i completely overlooked out2 and was trying to find if my loop is the problem.

Comment: Didn't that work ? What made you revert your acceptance ?

Comment: I am sorry that was by mistake . I am new to stackoverflow and still learning how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

var stringresult = JSON.stringify(yourobject or array);

Now you could print or alert it like alert(stringresult).